# Swift UIButton addTarget launch automattically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, addtarget

I have a little problem with my **addTarget** in **UIButton**. When I run my app, my function is automatically launched, while he is necessary to press the **UIButton** to launch. I don't know where is my problem.

My Button

```
let BTN_happy : UIButton = UIButton()
    BTN_happy.frame = CGRectMake(0, rowHeight * 1, fullWidth, rowHeight)
    BTN_happy.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#ff3b30")
    BTN_happy.addTarget(self, action: Selector(data("Happy")), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(BTN_happy)
    text("Happy", button: BTN_happy)
```

My Function

```
func text(text: String, button: UIButton) {

        let txt : UILabel = UILabel()
        txt.text = text.uppercaseString
        txt.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0, fullWidth - 40, button.bounds.size.height)
        txt.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#ffffff")
        txt.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(30, weight: UIFontWeightHeavy)
        txt.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
        txt.shadowColor = UIColor(hexString: "#000000", alpha: 0.3)

        button.addSubview(txt)

    }

    func data(mood: String) {
        NSLog("Mood: \(mood)")
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: can you elaborate this part of your code: `Selector(data("value"))`, please?

Comment: This is my fully UIButton and Functions

Comment: so I can tell you then, that is totally wrong; it is supposed to be `Selector("data:")`, if you have a `@IBAction func data(sender: UIButton) { ... }` somewhere in your class.

Comment: I don't have IBAction, I created my button programmatically, and also my function for get value of my UIButton.

Comment: ...and that is your `@IBAction` method, James.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a selector like that way. You need to change it like:

```
myBTN.addTarget(self, action: Selector("data:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Also change the method signature like:

```
func data(sender: UIButton)
{
   NSLog("Button clicked")
}
```

Comment: If I apply your method, I have this comment: Mood: <UIButton: 0x7ff6f316caa0; frame = (0 555.833; 375 111.167); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff6f3162520>>

Comment: @JamesHornet: Change the log and check again

Comment: @JamesHornet: That'll be the desired output, so what is your expectation

Comment: The log works, but I can't get my value when I press my UIButton

Comment: @JamesHornet: What value you need to pass ? Also you can't pass data through a selector that is attached to a button event

Answer (score 0):

For resolve my problem, I use tag in my **UIButton**.